# How do I use SuperAgent in a simple MVC 5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, bower, superagent

Okay, I know I should probably be able to figure this out, but I can't. I am trying to use SuperAgent.js in a simple HTML page in a MVC 5 app I am building. The project is a standard VS 2015 project for MVC and this is a blank HTML page more or less.

I was able to create a bower.json and reference the Superagent package. But I always get:
JavaScript runtime error: Module name "emitter" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I have this code, that I think is completely wrong:

```
<script src="~/wwwroot/lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
<script src="~/wwwroot/lib/superagent/lib/client.js"></script>
<script>
    var superagent = require('superagent');

    var data = superagent
        .get('/api/v1/ActualHourlyValues')
        .end(function (err, res) {
            // Calling the end function will send the request
        });
    alert(data);
</script>
```

I guess I just don't know the steps involved in using bower or npm to bring in a package like superagent so that I can use it to make AJAX calls.

I need steps from the creation of the HTMl! :)

Comment: might be you are using a script src that isn't valid. makes sense to use a script bundle instead.

Comment: Yeah I am starting to understand that, seems like I need to use Cassette to bundle the superagent package first. But, how?